# In angular 4 how can I make a reuseable button component which can enable a spinner when clicked

Tags: angular

Id like to create a reuseable button component which can enable a spinner when clicked and disable the spinner when the function ends.

I have tried with an eventEmitter from the button component. But then the button doesnt know when the function it has called ends and so it doesnt know when to stop the spinner.

I have tried to take the function it should call as an input but then all the funcctions I need to call will have to be exported where they are binded to the instance they are on.

Cant I somehow hook into the (click)="doStuff()" and start the spinner before the doStuff is called and hide the spinner when doStuff ends =)

I have made this example to show what Im looking for
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generalbutton-handlingspinner?file=app/app.component.html

I look forward to see what you can think up =)

Comment: Why not use `*ngIf="spinner"` that show the spinner. Then `(click)="spinner = !spinner; doStuff();"` and the when function finish `this.spinner = false` ?

Comment: Hi Swoox. Thx for answering. I know how to show and hide a spinner =) my issue here is to make a button that will solve it so I wont have to add hide spinner to all the methods I have in my program.

Comment: I assume most of those methods are async? You really need to show some short of code what you have now. We can't assume it's there if not explained or shown.

Comment: You are right Swoox. Ill make an example. Hold on.

Comment: Here is a sample. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generalbutton-handlingspinner?file=app/app.component.html

Ive tried to show what I want to achieve. But let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a service which will have show and hide boolean property as observable. Then you can create reusable component which has button and spinner. Then in that component you can import service and call show and hide whenever you want and also subscribe to that service and attach show and hide boolean value to your spinner.

**UPDATE :**

You can do spinner show and hide after method end using @Input. Pass function you want to execute to your reusable button component and execute that function in button component. And after execution stop the spinner. As method is executing inside button component it waits till your async operation gets completed and then stops spinner.

**progress-spinner.service.ts**

```
export class ProgressSpinnerService {

  constructor() { }

  private loaderSource = new Subject<ProgressSpinnerState>();

// Observable string streams
  loaderStateChanged$ = this.loaderSource.asObservable();

  show() {
    this.loaderSource.next(<ProgressSpinnerState>{ show: true });
  }
  hide() {
    this.loaderSource.next(<ProgressSpinnerState>{ show: false });
  }

}
```

**progress-spinner.component.ts**

```
export class ProgressSpinnerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() onClickFunction : any;

  show: boolean = false;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private loaderService: ProgressSpinnerService
  ) {
    this.subscription = loaderService.loaderStateChanged$
        .subscribe((state: ProgressSpinnerState) => {
            this.show = state.show;
        });
  }

  async startLoader(){
     this.loaderService.show();
     console.log("1 - The fire method on the button has started and the spinner is shown");
     await this.onClickFunction();
     console.log("4 - Now the fire method is done and the spinner is told to stop");
     this.loaderService.hide();
   }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**progress-spinner.component.html**

```
<button (click)="startLoader()">Start Loader</button>
<div *ngIf="show">
  <div>
    <mat-progress-spinner>
    </mat-progress-spinner>
    <br />
    <div>Please wait....</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can refer below

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypqkcf-eduhze)

Comment: Hi Ajinkya. Thx for answering. I have made almost the same solution as you suggest. But what I want to avoid is that I in all my methods will have to add show andd hide spinner. Id like some logic that wraps my button and then shows the spinner when the button is clicked and then hides it again once the function the button calls is done.

Comment: @user1338866 If your methods (doStuff()) are going to call have ajax call and if you want to hide spinner after that call gets completed, then you will have to call hide after call gets completed.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya1221.
Have a look here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-generalbutton-handlingspinner?file=app/app.component.html Ive tried to show what Im looking for.

Comment: @user1338866 Now I got your question , updated my answer !

Comment: Excelent. Only issue is that you will have to bind all methods to the class where they belong. Otherwise they wont have access to the instance variables.

For other who needs this you can read it here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions

But thx Ajinkya. This helped me =)

Comment: It would rock my world if we could somehow solve this without having to bind the methods =)

Comment: @OleBille you mean how to call variables from component, in which method resides?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean =) But it just seems like overhead that I have to do that for all methods. It might be the only way. I dont know.

Comment: @OleBille Yes, or you can also pass context (this) and argumets array along with method and do `this.method.apply(context, args);` in button component.